# No module named _pocketsphinx

Tags: pocketsphinx

I am trying do something on respeaker, but when I want to import pocketsphinx, something wrong, I think maybe .so file not match openwrt ,so what can i do.

> python: '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pocketsphinx/_pocketsphinx.so' is not an ELF file
>   error No module named _pocketsphinx

anyone have good idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file does not match your OS architecture, it was compiled for different OS.

You can try to install the proper version or compile software from source.